# What is the best way to query for instances of django models with one to one relationships with users

Tags: python, django

Let's say you have a django model with a OneToOne / Unique ForeignKey relationship with a User, as show on the [Django documentation on how to create a UserProfile.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users):

Now let's say you have a view method that takes a request you can get a user from.  What is the best way to query for the profile associated with that user?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# sample user profile model associated with user
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    likes_spam = models.BooleanField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

#view method
def forward_to_practice_home(request):
    user = request.user
    profile_for_user = #insert code here that would get the profile for that user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects)

Answer (score 2):

`related_name`s are very helpful. If you change your user profile definition to:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    likes_spam = models.BooleanField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
```

then you can use profile as follows:

```
def forward_to_practice_home(request):
    user = request.user
    profile_for_user = user.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a special method called [get_profile()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile)

```
profile_for_user = user.get_profile()
```

Be reminded that you have to set the [AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#auth-profiles) in the settings.py

However, this is deprecated in Django 1.5 because it adds the support of [user model customization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#auth-custom-user)